# How to set org.bouncycastle.rsa.allow_multi_use to true in java code

Tags: java, jboss7.x, bouncycastle

How to set org.bouncycastle.rsa.allow_multi_use to true in java code
An error is coming : org.bouncycastle.ceypro.IllegalKeyException:Attempt to sign/verify with RSA modulus already used for encrypt/decrypt.

When I searched in internet I got the answer if we set org.bouncycastle.rsa.allow_multi_use to true in java code then we'll get the Solution... Please help me solve this issue

Comment: Please share your code so that others can see what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood of the problem, the property needs to be set a system property. We too ran into the same issue and we did set this property as system property during the start up of our application and it worked.
org.bouncycastle.rsa.allow_multi_use = true

If you are on cloud, may be you can try this : https://docs.microfocus.com/itom/Hybrid_Cloud_Management:2020.05/FIPScompliance